# Combining Plots of functions with overlapping domains

Tags: plotting

I have a function

`H[J2_, j1b_, j1a_, eta_, x_, y_] =4 J2 Sqrt[(1 + eta (j1a/(2 J2) - j1b/(2 J2)) + (j1b Cos[y])/(
    2 J2))^2 - ((j1a Cos[x])/(2 J2) + Cos[x] Cos[y])^2]`

which I have to plot in 4 parts.

First part is with `y=0` and `x={0,Pi/2}`, second with `x=Pi/2` and `y={0,Pi}`. Then I have to plot the same function for the third part but with `y=Pi` and `x={Pi,0}` but x really have to go from $\pi/2$ to 0. And fourth part is with `x=0` and `y={Pi,0}`.

They have to be on the same graphics with the same H-axis. `J2`, `j1a`, `j1b`, `eta`, are constants.

Is there any way to do this? I tried with `GraphicsGrid` but it didn't work.

EDIT

It should look something like this:
[image: Picture of energy dispersion]

Comment: You can plot all the pieces separately and then use `Show`, which also allows you to adjust options such as `PlotRange`.

Comment: That wont work, or I don't know how. I need these four plots to be adjacent, with the separate abscissa's but same ordinate.

Comment: Then you need to provide a minimal working example with what you've tried.  For example, what J2, j1b, j1a, and eta are you using?

Comment: Just look at the first blue line with K1 and K2 points. My first plot is $\Gamma$ X section, second X M section etc.

Comment: I thnk you're better off defining a `Piecewise` function that captures all of the behavior you want.

Comment: I don't think because I effectively have two abscissas on the same scale. First I have $x=\{0,\pi/2\}$, then $y=\{0,\pi\}$ etc. And they are continuing one on another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the same lines as Bichoy's answer, and as per my suggestion to use `Piecewise`, consider the following solution:

```
H[J2_, j1b_, j1a_, eta_, x_, y_] := 4 J2 Sqrt[(1 + eta (j1a/(2 J2) - j1b/(2 J2)) 
            + (j1b Cos[y])/(2 J2))^2 - ((j1a Cos[ x])/(2 J2) + Cos[x] Cos[y])^2];
```

and build a `Piecewise` function from it:

```
PiecewiseH[J2b_,j1b_,j1a_,eta_,s_]:=Piecewise[{
    {H[J2b,j1b,j1a,eta,s,0],                  0<=s<\[Pi]/2},
    {H[J2b,j1b,j1a,eta,\[Pi]/2,s-\[Pi]/2],    \[Pi]/2<=s<3\[Pi]/2},
    {H[J2b,j1b,j1a,eta,2\[Pi]-s,\[Pi]],       3\[Pi]/2<= s<=2\[Pi]},
    {H[J2b, j1b, j1a, eta, 0, 3 \[Pi] - s],   2 \[Pi] <= s < 3 \[Pi]}
    }]
```

finally, using all 1s as the undisclosed constants,

```
Plot[PiecewiseH[1,1,1,1,s],{s,0,3\[Pi]}]
```

gives

[image: dispersion relation]

Comment: Thanks this is great and just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to map the `{x,y}` domain you need to a linear index say from `0` to `3`. Consider for example this function:

```
f1[n_] := {
  \[Pi]/2 Which[ n <= 1, n, 1 < n <= 2, 1, n > 2, 3 - n]
  ,
  \[Pi]/2 Which[n <= 1, 0, 1 < n <= 2, n - 1, n > 2, 3 - n]
  }
```

`f1[n]` for `0<n<3` will return a pair `{x,y}` that satisfies your requirements.

```
Table[f1[n], {n, 0, 3, 1/2}]
(*{{0, 0}, {\[Pi]/4, 0}, {\[Pi]/2, 0}, {\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/
  4}, {\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4}, {0, 0}} *)
```

Now, you just have to plot your function `h[__,f1[n]]` for `0<n<3`. (It is important to stick to the convention of the user-defined variables and functions starting with small letters to avoid collision with Mathematica internal functions). You can use the function `Table` to generate the different branches. You will need to label the ticks accordingly.

Here is an example (I didn't know how to substitute for J2, etc...):

```
Plot[
 Join @@ Table[h[j2, 0.3, 0.8, j2, 0.8, Sequence[f1[n]]], {j2, 1, 3}]
 
 , {n, 0, 3}, 
 Ticks -> {{{0, \[CapitalGamma]}, {1, X}, {2, 
     M}, {3, \[CapitalGamma]}}, Automatic}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I assume you can take it from here and proceed with more formatting and finding the right values.
(Nice dispersion relation BTW ... )

Answer (score 0):

```
p1 = Plot[H[1, 1, 1, 1, x, 0], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
p2 = Plot[H[1, 1, 1, 1, \[Pi]/2, y], {y, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red];
p3 = Plot[H[1, 1, 1, 1, x, \[Pi]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Green];
p4 = Plot[H[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, y], {y, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
```

[image]

Comment: That's not what I meant